# How to bind to collection's item's properties?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

How can I make intellisense work with item's properties of collection in xaml?

In runtime it works — CollectionView filled with data. But in xaml-editor there is `Cannot resolve property 'Name' in data context of type 'Questions.Pages.ObjectListViewModel'`.

*Object class:*

```cs
namespace Questions.Models
{
  public class MyObject
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
  }
}
```

*Page:*

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Questions.ViewModels;assembly=Questions"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Questions.Pages.ObjectListPage"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ObjectListViewModel}">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <CollectionView SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
      <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Num}"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

So, is there any way to specify type of collection's items?

Comment: Now I have not used this myself so not sure, but I think with `d:DataContext` you specify some information about the type the `DataContext` that the control and it's children will have. So since nothing else is specified it seems to expect the `Label` to have the same type (and therefor not have a `Name`) so you could try specifying the different type for the `StackLayout`: `StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:MyObject}"` and ofc don't forget to add the namespace as well. That said this is based on what I could find online, not on experience.

Comment: @Knoop it realy works! I have wasted about an hour, but could not find... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project!